# how to fetch raw YUV420p camera data

Tags: ios, camera, ffmpeg, rtmp, yuv

I don't know which value to use to fetch raw YUV420p data. code below first:

```
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
output.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES;
output.videoSettings = @{(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange]};
//output.videoSettings = @{(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]};

dispatch_queue_t queue;
queue = dispatch_queue_create("CameraQueue", NULL);
[output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];

[session addOutput:output];
```

I noticed that kCVPixelFormatType has some values, does somebody know which value is right to fetch raw YUV420p data?

```
kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8Planar
kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8PlanarFullRange
kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange
kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange
```

can be one of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on which particular YUV420 you want to get:
`Planar`/`Biplanar` refers to the arrangement of the luma and chroma components in memory, `Planar` meaning that each component comes in a buffer, contiguous or not, and `Biplanar` pointing to two buffers, one for luma and another for chroma, usually interleaved. An example of `Planar` is [YUV420](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php#IYUV) format and an example of `Biplanar` is [NV21](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php#NV21) or [NV12](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php#NV12)

`VideoRange` and `FullRange` refers to the values of the luma component, `Video` referring to  [16,235] accepted levels and `FullRange` to [0,255]. This confusing agreement comes from the MPEG standard ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Numerical_approximations))...